# Converting data to specified form

Tags: linux

I have data in the below mentioned form:

```
$& <abc>
This is a string .
$& <abc_def>
This is string two .
```

I want to convert the data given above to the below mentioned form:

```
This is a string <abc> .
This is string two <abc_def> .
```

I can perform such a transformation efficiently using python. Is there some way by which I may achieve the desired form using linux commands like sed, awk, etc.

Answer (score 1):

using sed yo can concatenate two lines and then make substitution

```
sed -n '/^$&/N;s/$& \(<.*>\)\n\([^\.]*\)/\2 \1 /;p ' <test.txt
```